# What is the name of this Google Play options Feature

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

The thing is I was browsing Google Play, and realized a very nice feature they add to the items in the application list. It's the **three dots that when you click it, a small panel with few options appear** (See image below). Does anyone know if its a new widget or something? Or if there's any tutorial or example that explains how to do it. Thank you.

[image: This is what I'm talking about]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a `PopupMenu`

> A `PopupMenu` displays a `Menu` in a modal popup window anchored to a `View`. The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or above it if there is not. If the IME is visible the popup will not overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will dismiss it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

It was added in API level 11

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

Comment: It has been backported to the [v7 support library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html) as well.